# Last jQuery tab element is duplicated in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, tabs, duplicates

I have some jQuery tabs set up on the right of the page, however in Safari the last tab link is duplicated i.e. "Static Page" is shown twice. This does not occur in other browsers. Any help as to why this happening.

http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/reviewit/review/quisque-ultricies-consequat/

This is my tab code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // We can use this object to reference the panels container
    var panelContainer = jQuery('div#panels');

    // Find panel names and create nav
    // -- Loop through each panel
    panelContainer.find('div.panel').each(function(n){
        // For each panel, create a tab
        jQuery('div#tabs-box ul').append('<li class="tab"><a href="#' + (n+1) + '">' + jQuery(this).attr('title') + '</a></li>');
    });

    // Determine which tab should show first based on the URL hash  
    var panelLocation = location.hash.slice(1);
        if(panelLocation == '1'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '2'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '3'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '4'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '5'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '6'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '7'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        } else if(panelLocation == '8'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;           
        } else if(panelLocation == '9'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;           
        } else if(panelLocation == '10'){
            var panelNum = panelLocation;
        }else{
            var panelNum = '1';
        }   
    // Hide all panels
    panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
    // Display the initial panel
    panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').fadeIn('slow');
    // Change the class of the current tab
    jQuery('div#tabs-box ul').find('li.tab:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').removeClass().addClass('tab-active');

    // What happens when a tab is clicked
    // -- Loop through each tab
    jQuery('div#tabs-box ul').find('li').each(function(n){
        // For each tab, add a 'click' action
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            // Hide all panels
            panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
            // Find the required panel and display it
            panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + (n+1) + ')').fadeIn('slow');
            // Give all tabs the 'tab' class
            jQuery(this).parent().find('li').removeClass().addClass('tab');
            // Give the clicked tab the 'tab-active' class
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('tab-active');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find method is returning an extra element for some reason, hard to tell why based on all the HTML. A stripped down example of your page works in Safari

To fix your script, if you search for just the elements with the class panel (instead of `div.panel`), it should work in Safari

```
panelContainer.find('.panel').each(function(n){
```